# AngularJS Dynamic Class - Background Image not working

Tags: angularjs, class, dynamic, conditional-statements, background-image

Unable to dynamically change class on "ng-repeat" list with background image contained in "style.css". Tried suggested solutions such as "ng-style="{ 'backgound-image': 'image_name.jpg' }" directly onto the element without much luck.

The class would need to change conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

ng-class to the rescue. Managed to achieve the conditional effect without needing to modify my "style.css".

Within my template "ng-repeat (item in productList)" i used the following, note your repeat will need to use the "track by $index" syntax:

```
<div ng-class="{ 'no' : 'image_off', 'yes': 'image_on' }[item.isOn]" ng-click="switchOnOff($index, item.productId, item.isOn); $event.stopPropagation();"></div>
```

NOTE: "$event.stopPropagation()" prevents the page submitting.

"image_off/image_on" refers to two different classes under my stylesheet. Each with their own respective background image.

In your controller use the following to action the event on the UI inside a function e.g "switchOnOff" :

```
$scope.productList[index].isOn = $scope.productList[index].isOn == 'no' ? 'yes' : 'no';
```